# Adding values in JTextFields in real time in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am writing a Java GUI program. I have two JTextFields:
'txtNet' and 'txtExcise'. I want values in these two textfields added as soon as I enter them and populate the result in another textfield 'txtTotal' without using a button.

Answer (score 1):

> I want values in these two textfields added as soon as I enter them
>   and populate the result in another textfield 'txtTotal' without using
>   a button.

This can be done using a [DocumentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) on the `JTextField`'s.

Here is a tutorial that covers the basics on how to use them: [How to Write a Document Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html)

---

Important extract from tutorial:

> Document events occur when the content of a document changes in any
>   way

This will allow you to monitor changes on the textfield values and react accordingly. For your case this would involve checking the values of the 2 inputs and provided both are valid, displaying the result in the output textfield

---

Here is a quick SSCCE ([Stack overflow glossary of acronyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)):

```
public class AutoCalculationDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField firstInput = new JTextField();
        JTextField secondInput = new JTextField();
        JTextField output = new JTextField();
        output.setEditable(false);

        DocumentListener additionListener = new DocumentListener() {
            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                attemptAddition();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                attemptAddition();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                attemptAddition();
            }

            public void attemptAddition(){
                try{
                    double firstValue = Double.parseDouble(firstInput.getText());
                    double secondValue = Double.parseDouble(secondInput.getText());
                    output.setText(String.valueOf(firstValue + secondValue));
                }catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
                    System.out.println("Invalid number(s) provided");
                }
            }
        };
        firstInput.getDocument().addDocumentListener(additionListener);
        secondInput.getDocument().addDocumentListener(additionListener);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
        panel.add(new JLabel("First number: "));
        panel.add(firstInput);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Second number: "));
        panel.add(secondInput);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Output: "));
        panel.add(output);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(250,150);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: for calculator is better (JTextField & numbers) to use DocumentFilter, then all code lines about Double.parse are useless...